# Call GrapQL mutation GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have this schema:

```
type Mutation {
  createUser(data: UserProps!): User!
}

input UserProps {
  name: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  image: String!
}
```

And I want to call the mutation

```
mutation {
  createUser(name: "Rodrigo", email: "email@example.com", password: "foobar", image: "https://...") {
    name,
    password
  }
}
```

But I got the error:

> {
> "error": {
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Unknown argument "name" on field "Mutation.createUser".",
> "extensions": {
> "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
> "exception": {
> "stacktrace": [
> "GraphQLError: Unknown argument "name" on field "Mutation.createUser".",
> "    at Object.Argument (/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/KnownArgumentNamesRule.js:46:29)",
> "    at Object.enter (/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:323:29)",
> "    at Object.enter (/app/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:370:25)",
> "    at visit (/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:243:26)",
> "    at validate (/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:69:24)",
> "    at validate (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:186:39)",
> "    at processGraphQLRequest (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:98:34)",
> "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
> "    at async processHTTPRequest (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runHttpQuery.js:187:30)"
> ]
> }
> }
> },
> {
> "message": "Unknown argument "email" on field "Mutation.createUser".",
> "extensions": {
> "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
> "exception": {
> "stacktrace": [
> "GraphQLError: Unknown argument "email" on field "Mutation.createUser".",
> "    at Object.Argument (/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/KnownArgumentNamesRule.js:46:29)",
> "    at Object.enter (/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:323:29)",
> "    at Object.enter (/app/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:370:25)",
> "    at visit (/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:243:26)",
> "    at validate (/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:69:24)",
> "    at validate (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:186:39)",
> "    at processGraphQLRequest (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:98:34)",
> "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
> "    at async processHTTPRequest (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runHttpQuery.js:187:30)"
> ]
> }
> }
> },

What can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

```
mutation {
  createUser(data: {name: "Rodrigo", email: "email@example.com", password: "foobar", image: "https://..."}) {
    name,
    password
  }
}
```